# are there any ASP.NET with Voice Recording sample codes?

Tags: asp.net, flash, voice-recording

I am wondering if there is any codes sample for ASP.NET with Voice recording.

Ok, Basically, i want to create a web page that allow user to click a record button and record his voice thru his/her microphone and then convert it into mp3 file, then i want to click PLAY button to play what was recorded.

I have searched google alot and cannot find any codes that code do just that.

I have seen site that can do just that and it is using FLASH with RoR (i think).

Is there any way to record voice using ASP.NET?
I dont care if it need to combine with FLASH with ASP.NET, as long as it is possible.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Stephen M. Redd,

Appreciate your input. Yes, i know there is no simple way to accomplish what i am asking for. I also have researched and google alot on this question. Yes,I have come to know the best way to do this is through using FLASH with either FMS or RED5 (open source).

So i am trying to figure out how to write a simple FLASH (.swf) that i can record voice and then save into mp3 format to RED5 server.

Do you know or can you provide any directions to what i am asking above?

1) Tutorial on Microphone class in FLASH (i am reading some basic implementation from a book called "FLASH Actionscript in a classroom", which doesnt tell me how to record voice but ONLY how to use microphone object in FLASH)

2) Tutorial on how to setup and use RED5 (FMS is NOT an option due to its cost)

3) how to integrate 1) and 2) with asp.net and javascript (if there is any flashvars that the FLASH microphon .swf i can access so that ASP.NET can be used with javascript)

Thanks.

EDIT 2:

I cant consider to accept an answer BECAUSE none of them has provided a good answer.

Take a look on my question and read the comments i got, and you will see that my question was NOT being provided a good answer.

My question is to find a web-based Audio/Voice recorder so that the users can record their voice on the site.

To better convey what i exactly asked for, take a look at www.snapvine.com or www.pubclip.com . Both of them provide a way for users to record their voice right on the webpage.

So, i am looking for a FLASH component (.swf) similar to what they offer to integrate with my site.

EDIT 3:

This voice/microphone recording thing seem to be a challenging project for most developers.

I guess this means i am all alone.

Comment: Just to clarity, what you want to do doesn't really have anything to do with ASP.NET. ASP.NET and RoR run on the server to handle requests & render something for the browser. If you want to use flash in the browser to record stuff, using ASP.NET for the back end doesn't affect this in any way.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is something that would have to be done with Flash.

This guy appears to have some examples of doing voice recording in Flash, with code samples:

http://fms.denniehoopingarner.com/

Comment: do u have any specific example that u can provide?
It seems to me that it is IMPOSSIBLE so far for ASP.NET

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way to do this kind of thing. Standard web technologies based on HTTP and HTML just don't have the features. HTTP doesn't work well with moving audio data, and HTML and Javascript are not able to talk directly to the hosting OS or hardware resources like the microphone.

There are 3rd party browser plug-ins and applets that you may be able to use via a web application to do this kind of thing.

Most people use Flash and the [Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/) to do audio input via the web.

There are also some Java applets that have similar capabilities such as the [ListenUp SDK](http://www.javasonics.com/) (I have not used this, so it isn't an endorsement).

There is a lot of discussion on this topic related to Microsoft Silverlight, but as I understand it voice and camera inputs from the client side are not supported as of Silverlight 2, though it may get put into Silverlight 3. There is a good bit of information about how to use the necessary Flash bits within a Silverlight application though. For more info on that, check out [this post](http://russellgreenspan.blogspot.com/2009/01/microphone-access-in-silverlight-via.html).

Answer (score 0):

ASP.net is a Server-Side Technology, but voice recording is done Client side. So regardless if you use ASP.net, PHP, Ruby on Rails or Cobol, you can't do it directly.

What you need is a Client-Side Application that works together with the Server Side to accomplish this. I do not know if Silverlight can do Microphone recording, but Flash can. This is apparently quite easy using the [Flash Media Interactive Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/), but normally you should be able to do this without, i.e. just by having a Flash Application doing the recording and then Uploading it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Sam in Silverlight 4 it is possible to record voice from microphone and webcams.

Just follow the blog.
http://blog.ondrejsv.com/post/Audio-recorder-Silverlight-4-sample.aspx

Good Luck