# How to use Red5 with Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, red5, voice-recording

I want to record voice online and I guess I need to use FMS or Red5 and I don't know how to use Red5 with Asp.net, actually this is my first attempt to handle such a thing and currently I am a .net developer.

So someone please show me a way to handle it and show me how to use Red5 with Asp.net.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't Red5 an open source Flash Server (http://osflash.org/red5)? If so what role are you hoping the ASP.NET framework to help with?

Comment: I used Red 5 and worked with our asp.net guy to build a chant creator :) And yeah it was completely free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the nice page which has very good infromation abou red ands ASP http://www.aspnetajaxchat.com/Deployment_Guide.pdf

http://www.freelancer-job.com/blog/2008/08/13/flash-aspnet-coder-to-integrate-red5-based-audiovideo-chat-module-to-aspnet-website-by-zukinet/

Some more information avilable in [are there any ASP.NET with Voice Recording sample codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571978/are-there-any-asp-net-with-voice-recording-sample-codes)

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully written an asp.net application to stream multiple users P2P video using Red5.

Integration of red5 is actually simple. Once you've got it working on your Server/VM  all you have to do is install the olfa Demo and you can write a player/streamer in flash. You just have to set the netconnections. One for the incoming stream and another for the outgoing stream. Then you'd have to add a mic & camera capture to attach them to the outgoing stream. If you want to make your player/Streamer more robust you can use a combination of Javascript and a webservice(AJAX) to control what streams to where.

You weren't very detailed on what you wanted to do otherwise I could have probably assisted you further.

For example code go to
http://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/#svn%2Fflash%2Ftrunk%253Fstate%253Dclosed