# Voice record in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash, twilio, voice-recording

After a big search i found voice recording is not possible in asp.net 4.

using plugin like flash we can achieve the same. 
can anyone share the code .net voice record and play using  flash player.

or if any other alternate good way to achieve this? kindly share the code.

Comment: the following links might help you http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/615255/Voice-Recording-in-asp-net-using-csharp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571978/are-there-any-asp-net-with-voice-recording-sample-codes http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0e185045-ef37-4a5d-a09b-05d26616bb84/voice-recording-uisng-c

Answer (score 0):

You dont use a normal asp.net site to do stuff like this. instead you should use Silverlight or flash. both technologies let you use the mic or webcam.

http://silvoicerecordupload.codeplex.com/

Silverlight and flash can both be implemented on a website regardless of web server.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is a server side technology that runs on the server. Audio recording is handled on the client side.

Flash is a current client side technology that has the ability to reliably capture audio from the user microphone, encode it and:

1. POST it to a (ASP.NET) web server OR
2. stream it to a media server like Red5, AMS or Wowza.

http://audior.ec does the former, http://flvar.com does the latter.

HTML5 might become a more feasible option in the future: http://audior.ec/blog/recording-mp3-using-only-html5-and-javascript-recordmp3-js/